# mui with nextjs 14 will be a problem for the server side?

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I am developing an application that needs mui for the user panel sections and seo for the main pages. I wanted to ask if there is any problem for the server side section.

If you know a better option than mui, let me know. I am familiar with tailwind, but due to the speed of development, I need ready-made components.